# What is the correct way to say: "He sings at the 6th minute of the video" or "in the in the 6th..."?

Tags: grammar

Let's say I am to watch a video where my friend is going to sing and the video is too long so I want to fast forward to the moment where he begings to sing, but I don't know what minute he sings in/at? What is the correct way to ask the question and what preposition do I use?

Comment: "Where (*or* when) does he begin singing?" . . . "At (*or* about*) minute 6." (*or* "At/about 6.0")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both prepositions can be used, but the placement of the preposition plus the use of ordinals or numerals is crucial.

You can say:

> He starts singing **at** the sixth minute

or you can say:

> He starts singing six minutes **in**

That last one is a shortened form of, "He starts singing six minutes **into the video**."

Comment: Is "six minutes into the video" not the seventh minute?

Comment: @Drossel - Nope, the video starts at minute zero. Six minutes into the video means six minute have elapsed, so the counter would be at 6:00. That said, I get what you're driving at; one could say that 6:00 to 6:59 is the seventh minute of the video, because 0:00 to 0:59 is the first minute of the video. But I don't think that's the way people generally regard it.

Comment: Right. I always forget that the first minute of video is two minutes long.

Comment: Not really. The first minute of the video runs from 0:00 to 0:59; the second minute of the video runs from 1:00 to 1:59, etc.